# Passing string to javascript function results in value

Tags: javascript, html

Something really odd going on here, and I have gone round in circles trying to figure out what is going on...I have a couple of input boxes, with onchange events firing for them, the event being loaded with a JS function that takes the value ( name of another item ) and actions the function accordingly. Only thing is, when the value of the string arrives at the other function, it has somehow been assigned a numeric value, specifically that of the input box.

My php that helps build the form:

```
$filterfield = '"p_delweek"';
print "<span class='filter'>Del Week<input class='menulink spin-button' id='weekno' type='text' value='".$weekno."' onKeyUp='doFilter($filterfield)' onChange='doFilter($filterfield)' data-filtered='0'/><input type='button' value='Clear' onClick='doUnfilter()'></span>";
$filterfield = '"p_seedweek"';
print "<span class='filter'>Sow Week<input class='menulink spin-button' id='sowweekno' type='text' value='".$weekno."' onKeyUp='doFilter($filterfield)' onChange='doFilter($filterfield)' data-filtered='0'/><input type='button' value='Clear' onClick='doUnfilter()'></span>";
```

Resulting HTML in source:

```
<span class="filter">Del Week<input style="width: 50px; height: 22px;" class="menulink spin-button smartspinner" id="weekno" value="26" onkeyup='doFilter("p_delweek")' onchange='doFilter("p_delweek")' data-filtered="0" type="text"><input value="Clear" onclick="doUnfilter()" type="button"></span><span class="filter">Sow Week<input style="width: 50px; height: 22px;" class="menulink spin-button smartspinner" id="sowweekno" value="26" onkeyup='doFilter("p_seedweek")' onchange='doFilter("p_seedweek")' data-filtered="0" type="text"><input value="Clear" onclick="doUnfilter()" type="button"></span>
```

Javascript function that is called:

```
function doFilter(filterfield) {
    console.log("DoFilter:"+filterfield);

    var filterInfo=[
        {
            fieldName : filterfield,
            logic : "equal",
            value : Sigma.Util.getValue("weekno")
        }
    ]

    // the next lines action the filtering
    var grid=Sigma.$grid("myGrid1");
    console.log("filterinfo="+filterInfo);
    var rowNOs=grid.applyFilter(filterInfo); 
}
```

It all goes fine until we get to the console.log("DoFilter:"+filterfield) , which results in  DoFilter:25; 25 happens to be the value of the input box.

How is it grabbing that value? How to pass the real one?

Comment: Try `console.log('filterinfo=', filterInfo)` or simply `console.log(filterInfo)`. The best-case scenario for using `+` the way you are now is for it to output something like `filterinfo=[object Object]`. You can't add a string and an array this way.

Comment: @meagar Although I agree with you on that point, the problem in question is related with the first `console.log`, not with the second.

Comment: @Onyx What browser are you testing in? I ran your code in Safari, Chrome and Firefox for the Mac and saw 'DoFilter:p_delweek' each and every time.

Comment: Testing this in Firefox 64bit on Linux, and Chromium on same 64bit Debian Wheezy. Same results on each. I do get [object Object] as expected for the second console.log, I know that part is working :)

Comment: Just built a basic html page, with the code above, and it works as it should. Sorry for wasting your time everyone, there is obviously something else coming along and changing the result in the original page.

Comment: Aha! the problem lies somewhere in the extra js file called smartspinner.js, which is used to turn an input into a spin control... will add the code as an answer below, even though it is not an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH — I'm not sure if I got what you're after. However, if you must call a function inline (I recommend that you don’t), you can pass a reference to the input field as parameter and make it available in the methods’s body:

```
<input onchange="doFilter('p_delweek', this)" type="text">
```

​

```
function doFilter(filterfield, field) {
    console.log(filterfield);
    // field is a reference to the input field, hence
    console.log(field.value);
    // will print the current value for this field
}
```

Comment: I agree with @polarblau that you should try and avoid using inline functions. I would go further suggest the use of JQuery and its .on() method to bind actions on the key events.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am not trying to pass the input over at all, as your code allows for, I just wanted the doFilter('p_delweek') to pass 'p_delweek' over to the function...it doesn't, and hence I am baffled! Especially as natlee75 above gets correct results, and there is nothing glaringly obvious to you all that I am doing wrong.

Comment: I have accepted your answer because it is technically correct, as I did not supply the complete source code causing the stuff up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, this file is the problem:

```
        (function($) {
        $.fn.extend({
            spinit: function(options) {
                var settings = $.extend({ min: 0, max: 100, initValue: 0, callback: doFilter, stepInc: 1, pageInc: 10, width: 50, height: 15, btnWidth: 10, mask: '' }, options);
                return this.each(function() {
                    var UP = 38;
                    var DOWN = 40;
                    var PAGEUP = 33;
                    var PAGEDOWN = 34;
                    var mouseCaptured = false;
                    var mouseIn = false;
                    var interval;
                    var direction = 'none';
                    var isPgeInc = false;
                    var value = Math.max(settings.initValue, settings.min);
                    var el = $(this).val(value).css('width', (settings.width) + 'px').css('height', settings.height + 'px').addClass('smartspinner');
                    raiseCallback(value);
                    if (settings.mask != '') el.val(settings.mask);
                    $.fn.reset = function(val) {
                        if (isNaN(val)) val = 0;
                        value = Math.max(val, settings.min);
                        $(this).val(value);
                        raiseCallback(value);
                    };
                    function setDirection(dir) {
                        direction = dir;
                        isPgeInc = false;
                        switch (dir) {
                            case 'up':
                                setClass('up');
                                break;
                            case 'down':
                                setClass('down');
                                break;
                            case 'pup':
                                isPgeInc = true;
                                setClass('up');
                                break;
                            case 'pdown':
                                isPgeInc = true;
                                setClass('down');
                                break;
                            case 'none':
                                setClass('');
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    el.focusin(function() {
                        el.val(value);
                    });
                    el.click(function(e) {
                        mouseCaptured = true;
                        isPgeInc = false;
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        onValueChange();
                    });
                    el.mouseenter(function(e) {
                        el.val(value);
                    });
                    el.mousemove(function(e) {

                        if (e.pageX > (el.offset().left + settings.width) - settings.btnWidth - 4) {
                            if (e.pageY < el.offset().top + settings.height / 2)
                                setDirection('up');
                            else
                                setDirection('down');
                        }
                        else
                            setDirection('none');
                    });
                    el.mousedown(function(e) {
                        isPgeInc = false;
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        interval = setTimeout(onValueChange, 250);
                    });
                    el.mouseup(function(e) {
                        mouseCaptured = false;
                        isPgeInc = false;
                        clearInterval(interval);

                    });
                    el.mouseleave(function(e) {
                        setDirection('none');
                        if (settings.mask != '') el.val(settings.mask);
                    }); el.keydown(function(e) {
                        switch (e.which) {
                            case UP:
                                setDirection('up');
                                onValueChange();
                                break; // Arrow Up
                            case DOWN:
                                setDirection('down');
                                onValueChange();
                                break; // Arrow Down
                            case PAGEUP:
                                setDirection('pup');
                                onValueChange();
                                break; // Page Up
                            case PAGEDOWN:
                                setDirection('pdown');
                                onValueChange();
                                break; // Page Down
                            default:
                                setDirection('none');
                                break;
                        }
                    });

                    el.keyup(function(e) {
                        setDirection('none');
                    });
                    el.keypress(function(e) {
                        if (el.val() == settings.mask) el.val(value);
                        var sText = getSelectedText();
                        if (sText != '') {
                            sText = el.val().replace(sText, '');
                            el.val(sText);
                        }
                        if (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) {
                            var temp = parseFloat(el.val() + (e.which - 48));
                            if (temp >= settings.min && temp <= settings.max) {
                                value = temp;
                                raiseCallback(value);
                            }
                            else {
                                e.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    el.blur(function() {
                        if (settings.mask == '') {
                            if (el.val() == '')
                                el.val(settings.min);
                        }
                        else {
                            el.val(settings.mask);
                        }
                    });
                    el.bind("mousewheel", function(e) {
                        if (e.wheelDelta >= 120) {
                            setDirection('down');
                            onValueChange();
                        }
                        else if (e.wheelDelta <= -120) {
                            setDirection('up');
                            onValueChange();
                        }

                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                    if (this.addEventListener) {
                        this.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
                            if (e.detail > 0) {
                                setDirection('down');
                                onValueChange();
                            }
                            else if (e.detail < 0) {
                                setDirection('up');
                                onValueChange();
                            }
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }, false);
                    }

                    function raiseCallback(val) {
                        if (settings.callback != null) settings.callback(val);
                    }
                    function getSelectedText() {

                        var startPos = el.get(0).selectionStart;
                        var endPos = el.get(0).selectionEnd;
                        var doc = document.selection;

                        if (doc && doc.createRange().text.length != 0) {
                            return doc.createRange().text;
                        } else if (!doc && el.val().substring(startPos, endPos).length != 0) {
                            return el.val().substring(startPos, endPos);
                        }
                        return '';
                    }
                    function setValue(a, b) {
                        if (a >= settings.min && a <= settings.max) {
                            value = b;
                        } el.val(value);
                    }
                    function onValueChange() {
                        if (direction == 'up') {
                            value += settings.stepInc;
                            if (value > settings.max) value = settings.max;
                            setValue(parseFloat(el.val()), value);
                        }
                        if (direction == 'down') {
                            value -= settings.stepInc;
                            if (value < settings.min) value = settings.min;
                            setValue(parseFloat(el.val()), value);
                        }
                        if (direction == 'pup') {
                            value += settings.pageInc;
                            if (value > settings.max) value = settings.max;
                            setValue(parseFloat(el.val()), value);
                        }
                        if (direction == 'pdown') {
                            value -= settings.pageInc;
                            if (value < settings.min) value = settings.min;
                            setValue(parseFloat(el.val()), value);
                        }
                        raiseCallback(value);
                    }
                    function setClass(name) {
                        el.removeClass('up').removeClass('down');
                        if (name != '') el.addClass(name);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Why and where does this alter the passing value of a function attached to the < INPUT > ?

Comment: Got it, it's the callback in the settings line. And it was not able to handle the passing of the variable. So I have worked around it, by using multiple callbacks sent to the smartspinner at it's initialization, eg  jQuery('#sowweekno').spinit({min:1,max:53,stepInc:1,pageInc:20, height: 22, initValue: currentWeek, callback:doFilter2 });